# Mysql spaceship operator for like and limit, offset

Tags: php, mysql

I want to check, variable null or not. Are there any operator for LIKE, LIMIT or OFFSET query?

I could use <=> (spaceship operator) for equals.

Here is my query :

```
public function getFaqs($limit = null, $offset = null, $search = null) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM faq GROUP BY id LIMIT ? OFFSET ?";
        $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute(array($limit, $offset));
        if ($query->rowCount() > 0)
            return $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return null;
    }
```

If i didn't send limit or offset parameter. That query is not work, because limit is null. I don't want to write too many if conditions. If limit is null don't bind bla bla.....

Are there any operator in mysql for this ?

Comment: Set defaults that aren't `null` for `$limit` and `$offset` (e.g. PHP_INT_MAX and 0 respectively); and the "LIKE operator" in MySQL is `%`

Comment: The use of `select *` with `group by` suggests a profound misunderstanding of SQL.

Comment: @MarkBaker What should the default limit be?

Comment: `(e.g. PHP_INT_MAX and 0 respectively);`